# Criar um Webapp de Controle de estoque

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, estou aprendendo Javascript e tenho uma duvida. Tenho conhecimento já em HTML, CSS e SQL

Quais linguagens eu preciso para criar um sistema (controle de estoque) que adiciona , altera (já adicionado) e exclui, elemento através  de pesquisa  interna no site com javascript.

Quero também armazenar os dados do cliente, no client-side, para que ele possa abrir em seu sistema os dados guardados, que ele já tem, e possa ser armazenado em armazenamentos portátil.

Já tenho um código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Evento de Botão</title>
    <style>
  input, button {
    padding: .5em;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 100%;
  }

  th, td {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="codigo" placeholder="insira o codigo do produto">
    <input type="text" id="precoCompra" placeholder="preco de compra">
    <input type="text" id="precoVenda" placeholder="preco de venda">
    <button id="btn-adicionar">
        Adcionar
    </button>
    <button id="btn-alterar">
        Alterar
    </button>
       <div id="pesquisa" hidden> 
            <input type="text" placeholder="pesquise o codigo" id="campoPesquisa">
       </div>
     <table id="dados" hidden>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo do Produto</th>
                <th>preço compra</th>
                <th>preço Venda</th>
                <th>lucro</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
      </table>

    <script>
        const codigo       = document.querySelector('#codigo')
        const precoCompra  = document.querySelector('#precoCompra')
        const precoVenda   = document.querySelector('#precoVenda')
        const btn          = document.querySelector('#btn-adicionar')
        const dados        = document.querySelector('#dados')
        const btnAlterar   = document.querySelector('#btn-alterar')
        const tbody        = document.querySelector('tbody')
        const pesquisa    = document.querySelector('#pesquisa')
        const campopesquisa= document.querySelector('#campoPesquisa')
        codigo.focus()

        btn.addEventListener('click', e=>{
            let compra = +precoCompra.value
            let venda  = +precoVenda.value 
            let valorFinal = 0
                if (compra && venda && codigo){
                    valorFinal = venda - compra



                    dados.removeAttribute('hidden')

                    tbody.innerHTML += `<tr>
                                            <td class="codproduto">${codigo.value}</td> 
                                            <td>${compra}</td> 
                                            <td>${venda}</td>
                                            <td>${valorFinal}</td>
                                        </tr>`

                    codigo.value = ''
                    precoCompra.value = ''
                    precoVenda.value = ''
                    codigo.focus()   
                                                   }


        })

        btnAlterar.addEventListener('click', e=>{
            /*
            if(tbody){
                pesquisa.removeAttribute('hidden')
                let search = campopesquisa.value 

            }
            */
            pesquisa.removeAttribute('hidden')

            for( let c of document.querySelectorAll(".codproduto") )
            {
                console.log(c.innerHTML)
            }
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você vai precisar ter uma bagagem boa de javascript. Para o otimizar seu trabalho você pode usar algum framework como reactjs. Para armazenar dados no cliente-side você pode usar o alguma biblioteca como sql.js

Comment: Ainda estou no Inicio mais Aprendo rápido, vou da uma olhada no reactjs

Comment: Boa noite, trabalho atualmente em uma empresa de sistema de transportadora e ja tenho bastante experiencia e bagagem nesse tipo de sistema, a forma mais correta e segura é você trabalhar com java no back-end e usar um banco de dados ( no meu caso uso e prefiro o postgres ), recomendo você estudar um pouco e entender o funcionamento de servlet e o padrão MVC, sobre onde e quando tratar regra de negocio e coisa do tipo, assim você vai ter um sistema estável e seguro.

Comment: Muito obrigado vou seguir sua dica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na minha visão não siga receitas de bolo, antes pesquise e veja se encaixa em sua necessidade.

Necessariamente você vai precisar de tecnologias front(html, css e js) e back(tem varias)...

Pelo que entendi na sua pergunta, você quer ter bastante interação no client, sugeriria um framework SPA como o angular ou uma biblioteca como react e vue.

De alguma forma ira precisar de alguém no server,servindo seu client. Se quiser utilizar somente javascript(client e server), pode utilizar node.js.

De uma pesquisada sobre essas tecnologias e comece aprendendo elas na pratica criando o "protótipo" da sua ideia, isso vai te dar um bom resultado, tanto para o futuro da sua ideia e motivação de aprendizado.